# How the append and delete the value of a checkbox to an ul li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul class="checklist">
  <li><span><cite></cite></span><b>List 1</b></li>
  <li><span><cite></cite></span><b>List 2</b></li>
  <li><span><cite></cite></span><b>List 3</b></li>
  <li><span><cite></cite></span><b>List 4</b></li>
</ul>
<ul class="append-checklist">
</ul> 

$('.checklist li').click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("active-checklist");
});

.checklist li b 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #555454;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color:#a7a7a7;
}
.checklist li.active-checklist b
{
    color: #202020;
    font-size:inherit;
    top:2px;
}
.checklist li,.active-checklist li
{
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.checklist
{
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding:0;
}

.checklist li span
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}
.checklist li.active-checklist span
{
    border: 1px solid #49a1d7;
}
.checklist li span cite
{
    display: none;
}
.checklist li.active-checklist span cite
{
    position: relative;
    left: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #49a1d7;
    border: none;
}
```

I need to append the value of the checklist li to the list of the append-checklist once the checklist li has the class active and remove the value once active class is removed from the checklist li. Thanks in advance. Please refer to the fiddle. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hC35Y/)

Comment: `I need to append the value of the checklist li to the list of the append-checklist once the checklist li has the class active and remove the value once active class is removed from the checklist li.` Full Confused. Can you explain little brief?

Comment: All I need to append my li value from checklist to my li of append-checklist once my checklist li has class active. Similarly if the active class is removed from the li the values should also removed from the append-checklist li.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `.clone()` the selected `li`s and then `.append()` it into the other UL as per your wish,

```
$('.checklist li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-checklist");
    $('ul.append-checklist').empty().append($(this).closest('ul').find('.active-checklist').clone())
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hC35Y/6/)

As per your new requirement use,

```
$('.checklist li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-checklist");
    $('ul.append-checklist').html($.map($(this).closest('ul').find('.active-checklist '),function(elem,i){ return "<li>" + $(elem).text() + '</li>'; }))
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hC35Y/12/)

Comment: The above code clones the entire li to the append-checklist all i need to remove the span and cite attr from the li when it append to the li of append-checklist. And also i need a close symbol which will remove the li when it is clicked.

Comment: @Benjamin wait i am working on it.. give me 3 mins. :)

Comment: Thanks again for the effort u made.:)

Comment: What do the map function doing for can u explain me a bit

Comment: @Benjamin It would translate a collection into another collection of our required format. Have a look at the [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this : check if clicked `li` has `class="active-checklist"` then make clone of it and add it to `append-checklist`, otherwise remove from `append-checklist`.

```
$('.checklist li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-checklist");
    if($(this).hasClass('active-checklist'))
     $(this).clone().appendTo('.append-checklist');
    else
     $('.append-checklist').find('li:contains('+$(this).text()+')').remove();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hC35Y/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works however is not robust as if you have list items with the same text they will `collide` consider adding `id`s either via the `data` attribute in jQuery.

```
$('.checklist li').click(function () {
    var me = $(this);
    me.toggleClass("active-checklist");
    if (me.hasClass('active-checklist')) {
        me.clone().appendTo('.append-checklist');
    } else {
        // remove me
        $('.append-checklist li:contains(' + me.text() + ')').remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/hC35Y/3/